# appending <form> above the previous <form> or multiple <form> tags using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dhtml

I am working on a webpage which has a comment box using which a person can comment, these comments are displayed on the same page dynamically using AJAX. For example, when you submit a comment it gets posted on top of the previous comments.

Here is what i'm doing in AJAX:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

            var newDivElement = document.createElement('form');
            newDivElement.setAttribute('id',"postForm");
            newDivElement.setAttribute('action',"updateRecords.php");
            newDivElement.setAttribute('method',"post");
            newDivElement.innerHTML=postContent; 

            document.getElementById('mainPostContainer').appendChild(newDivElement);
        }
    }
```

(`postcontent` consists of a div which contains the comment)

Now, if I post two consecutive comments, say "this is 1st comment" and "this is 2nd comment", they get posted in the following order:

```
<div id=mainPostContainer>
    <form id="postForm" action="updateRecords.php" method="post"><div id="post"> this is 1st comment </div></form>
    <form id="postForm" action="updateRecords.php" method="post"><div id="post"> this is 2nd comment </div></form>
</div>
```

But I want them in the following order:

```
<div id=mainPostContainer>
    <form id="postForm" action="updateRecords.php" method="post"><div id="post"> this is 2nd comment </div></form>
    <form id="postForm" action="updateRecords.php" method="post"><div id="post"> this is 1st comment </div></form>
</div>
```

I tried using `insertBefore()` instead of append, but I dont know how to get the previous element (ie. the last created `<form>`).

Am I doing something wrong here? Or is there a better way to do what I am trying to do? Maybe using jQuery?

**EDIT**: I am using `<form>` because there are input elements of type button and text inside the form, I didnt mention them just to keep it simple.

Comment: The opposite of `.append()` would be a `.prepend()`

Comment: try with id="postForm1" and id="postForm2" and try using .prepend() http://api.jquery.com/prepend/ hope it helps.

Comment: In addition, you could also use a single `form` differentiating the various posts by id

Comment: Why are you using `<form>`s with no form elements (like input, select) inside? Also, are you really using jQuery? The code you posted is plain js. We need to know if we can suggest you a jQuery solution or not.

Comment: @bfavaretto: i have input elements like buttons and text inside, i didnt mention it just for the sake of simplicity, i will edit the post now to clarify.

Comment: @bfavaretto yes, i am using plain javascript right now, i would like to know a better way to accomplish what i am trying to do using jquery.

Comment: @vineetrok Okay, you already have two answers below, one using plain js, and another one with jQuery. Looks like the problem is solved!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Adding New Element as the First Child

### Plain Old JavaScript

**HTML:**

```
<div id="mainPostContainer"><p>1</p></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var myContainer = document.getElementById("mainPostContainer");
var p = document.createElement("p");
p.innerHTML = "2";
myContainer.insertBefore(p,myContainer.firstChild);
```

**Example:**

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gWpbY/)

---

### jQuery

**HTML:**

```
<div id="mainPostContainer"><p>1</p></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var p = $("<p>2</p>");
$("#mainPostContainer").prepend(p);
```

**Example:**

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jqaYe/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Jquery method "prepend()". http://api.jquery.com/prepend/
Try doing something like this:

```
$('#mainPostContainer').prepend(newDivElement);
```

Also, be careful while using "innerHTML" it doesn't update the DOM directly. So if the you need to refer to any element inside the postContent you won't be able to, because the DOM won't see it.
A better approach would be to create every element that you might need to reference using the createElement() function of javascript.

Also you might want to give your IDs a unique identifier, probably something from the Database (not directly if sensitive information is involved).